# How to (Conditionally) event handling(cancel) and alert message(Key event) in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, ckeditor

I want to conditionally cancel the key event and also show alert.

In below code :the mode is true when  startElement's contenteditable  attribute is false

*in ckeditor.js:*

```
on("key",function(j){
if(mode==false)
{
j.cancel();
}
.......
```

Above code cancel the event(working)

```
on("key",function(j){
if(mode==false)
{
j.cancel();
alert("somthing..");
}......
```

Above code alert working but event didn't cancel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try giving the browser priority on canceling the event. I didn't try it, but I assume the following should work:

```
on( 'key', function( j ) {
if( mode == false ) {
    j.cancel();
    setTimeout( function() {
        alert( 'somthing..' );
    },0);
}
```